Power options do not work with custom shell launcher
I am using the Windows Shell Launcher on Windows to start a Chrome application. That does work so far. I have also tried to configure Winows to shut down after a certain time. I have tried it with the Group Policies and the Power Options of the user, but Windows never shuts down.
Do the settings not work anymore because I replaced the explorer.exe with the a chrome.exe?
